# Using RecyclerView with DataBase

Tags: java, android

```
public class Contact {

// id
int mNumber;

String  mMonth,mDate, mDay, mTime , mTitle , mContent;
int mMood,mWeather;

public Contact(){}

public Contact(int number, String month, String date, String day, String time, String title, String content, int weather, int mood) {
    mNumber=number; mMonth=month; mDay = day; mDate = date ; mTime = time; mTitle = title; mContent = content; mWeather = weather; mMood =mood;
}

public Contact(String month, String date, String day, String time, String title, String content, int weather, int mood) {
    mMonth=month; mDay = day; mDate = date ; mTime = time; mTitle = title; mContent = content; mWeather = weather; mMood =mood;
}
public Contact(String month, String date, String day, String time, String title, String content) {
    mMonth=month; mDay = day; mDate = date ; mTime = time; mTitle = title; mContent = content;
}


public int getmNumber() {
    return mNumber;
}

public void setmNumber(int mNumber) {
    this.mNumber = mNumber;
}

public String getmMonth() {
    return mMonth;
}

public void setmMonth(String mMonth) {
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public String getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}

public void setmDay(String mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}

public String getmTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setmTime(String mTime) {
    this.mTime = mTime;
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public String getmContent() {
    return mContent;
}

public void setmContent(String mContent) {
    this.mContent = mContent;
}

public int getmMood() {
    return mMood;
}

public void setmMood(int mMood) {
    this.mMood = mMood;
}

public int getmWeather() {
    return mWeather;
}

public void setmWeather(int mWeather) {
    this.mWeather = mWeather;
}
}
```

Contact class is use to save value

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Calendar.db";

//Table Name
public static final String D_TABLE_NAME = "Diary";

public static final String D_COL_1 = "m_Number";  //id
public static final String D_COL_2 = "m_Title";
public static final String D_COL_3 = "m_Content";
public static final String D_COL_4 = "m_Month";   
public static final String D_COL_5 = "m_Date";     
public static final String D_COL_6 = "m_Day"; 
public static final String D_COL_7 = "m_Time";        
public static final String D_COL_8 = "m_Mood";    //image 
public static final String D_COL_9 = "m_Weather"; //image

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+D_TABLE_NAME+"("+D_COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+D_COL_2+" TEXT, "+D_COL_3+" TEXT, "+D_COL_4+" TEXT, "
                +D_COL_5+" TEXT, "+D_COL_6+" TEXT, "+D_COL_7+ " TEXT, "+D_COL_8+" INTEGER, "+D_COL_9+" INTEGER);");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}


//Insert new Data
public void addContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(D_COL_2,contact.getmTitle());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_3,contact.getmContent());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_4,contact.getmMonth());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_5,contact.getmDate());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_6,contact.getmDay());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_7,contact.getmTime());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_8,contact.getmMood());
    contentValues.put(D_COL_9,contact.getmWeather());

    db.insert(D_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    db.close();

}   // 

// mNumber to get Contact 
public Contact getContact(int mNumber) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(D_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { D_COL_1,D_COL_2,D_COL_3,D_COL_4,D_COL_5,
                    D_COL_6,D_COL_7,D_COL_8,D_COL_9 }, D_COL_1 + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(mNumber) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
    return contact;
}

// All Contact information get
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + D_TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setmNumber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setmTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setmContent(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setmMonth(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setmDate(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setmDay(cursor.getString(5));
            contact.setmTime(cursor.getString(6));
            contact.setmMood(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            contact.setmWeather(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return contact list
    Log.d("agent99", contactList.get(0).getmTitle().toString());

    return contactList;
}


public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(D_COL_2,contact.getmTitle());
    values.put(D_COL_3,contact.getmContent());
    values.put(D_COL_4,contact.getmMonth());
    values.put(D_COL_5,contact.getmDate());
    values.put(D_COL_6,contact.getmDay());
    values.put(D_COL_7,contact.getmTime());
    values.put(D_COL_8,contact.getmMood());
    values.put(D_COL_9,contact.getmWeather());

    // updating row
    return db.update(D_TABLE_NAME, values, D_COL_1 + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getmNumber()) });
}

// Contact information delete
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(D_TABLE_NAME, D_COL_1 + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getmNumber()) });
    db.close();
}

// Contact information number 
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + D_TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

Recycler Adapter class DataManager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.codbking.calendar.Contact;
import com.codbking.calendar.DBHelper;
import com.codbking.calendar.exaple.R;
import java.util.List;

public class DataManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {
DBHelper dbHelper;
CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

List<Contact> contacts = dbHelper.getAllContacts();


public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mDate, mDay, mMonth, mTime, mTitle, mContent;
    ImageView mMood, mWeather;
    private Context context;



    RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_date);
        mDay = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_day);
        mMonth = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_header);
        mTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_time);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_title);
        mContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_entries_item_summary);
        mMood = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.IV_entries_item_weather);
        mWeather = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.IV_entries_item_mood);

        itemView.setClickable(true);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.entries, viewGroup, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    // get the single element from the main array

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        viewHolder.mDate.setText(cn.getmDate());
        viewHolder.mDay.setText(cn.getmDay());
        viewHolder.mMonth.setText(cn.getmMonth());
        viewHolder.mTime.setText(cn.getmTime());
        viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cn.getmTitle());
        viewHolder.mContent.setText(cn.getmContent());
        viewHolder.mMood.setImageResource(cn.getmMood());
        viewHolder.mWeather.setImageResource(cn.getmWeather());

    }


}
@Override
public int getItemCount(){
   return contacts.size();
}
}
```

I don't know how to use RecyclerView with DataBase. 
Error occur in DataManager Class (confidence)
Maybe Error occur in `onBindViewHolder()` Method or `getItemCount()` Method. 
Previously I use RecyclerView without DataBase App run well... But when I use DataBase, App is just die so I surely die  `onBindViewHolder()` Method or `getItemCount()` Method in this code

Comment: Basically you are setting all contact information in loop for every single position. The answer by Pankaj Sharma is the right code to use.

Comment: Thank you for answer , but App is die .. I think answer code is right too

Comment: You have not connected your dbHelper to the context from where your are calling the DataManager

Comment: You need to send the context and in the constructor of DataManager, then in the constructor only, initialize the dbHelper like this dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

Comment: Context context;
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context); Like this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your onBindViewHolder code with this one

```
       @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
     // get the single element from the main array
        Contact cn = contact.get(i);
        viewHolder.mDate.setText(cn.getmDate());
        viewHolder.mDay.setText(cn.getmDay());
        viewHolder.mMonth.setText(cn.getmMonth());
        viewHolder.mTime.setText(cn.getmTime());
        viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cn.getmTitle());
        viewHolder.mContent.setText(cn.getmContent());
        viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cn.getmTitle());
        viewHolder.mContent.setText(cn.getmContent());
        viewHolder.mMood.setImageResource(cn.getmMood());
        viewHolder.mWeather.setImageResource(cn.getmWeather());

      }
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer! Contact cn = contacts.get(i) you mean this right ? But App is die..

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
       return contacts.size();
    }  This code is right?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all data in a loop. That is not correct for recycler view. You can use the below code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Contact cn = contact.get(i);
    if (cn != null){
    viewHolder.mDate.setText(cn.getmDate());
    viewHolder.mDay.setText(cn.getmDay());
    viewHolder.mMonth.setText(cn.getmMonth());
    viewHolder.mTime.setText(cn.getmTime());
    viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cn.getmTitle());
    viewHolder.mContent.setText(cn.getmContent());
    viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cn.getmTitle());
    viewHolder.mContent.setText(cn.getmContent());
    viewHolder.mMood.setImageResource(cn.getmMood());
    viewHolder.mWeather.setImageResource(cn.getmWeather());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Its better to check for the null object, so that it will not crash your app.

Comment: Thank you for answer!! But Contact cn = contacts.get(i) you mean this right ? But App is die..

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago I was trying use a Cursor to populate a RecyclerView. There​ is not something like a CursorAdapter for a RecyclerView, you must create your own implementation.

I found a nice tutorial where use a Cursor and a CursorLoader to populate the recView asynchronously. The tutorial is in Spanish but the code is pretty clear a works nice for my app.

http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/01/recyclerview-con-cursor-en-android/